# finding all lines in a list that contain x or y?

Tags: c#, list, .net-4.0

can I do this without looping through the whole list?

```
List<string> responseLines = new List<string>();
```

the list is then filled with around 300 lines of text.

next I want to search the list and create a second list of all lines that either start with "abc" or contain "xyz".

I know I can do a for each but is there a better / faster way?

Comment: Linq is awesome for this stuff :)

Comment: If you keep your list sorted then you can find all the lines that start with "abc" without having to loop over all of them, but you can't find ones that contain "xyz" without looking at each one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use LINQ. This is no different performance-wise to using `foreach` -- that's pretty much what it does behind the scenes -- but you might prefer the syntax:

```
var query = responseLines.Where(s => s.StartsWith("abc") || s.Contains("xyz"))
                         .ToList();
```

(If you're happy dealing with an `IEnumerable<string>` rather than `List<string>` then you can omit the final `ToList` call.)

Comment: Note that this still loops through the whole list, you just didn't have to write the `foreach` yourself.

Comment: FYI - the `Contains` should be "xyz"

Comment: This iterating over each character in each line.

Comment: thanks but when I try this I get:
System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Adrian - you need `using System.Linq;`

Comment: @Svisstack: What do you mean?

Comment: Make sure that System.Linq namespace is referenced. Anyway, what you ask is impossible to do without iteration. What you can do, as suggested, is using LINQ methods and lambda extensions to write in a simple statement what it would require maybe 10 or more lines in old fashioned syntax.

Comment: Thanks I was indeed missing the using.

Comment: @LukeH: i mean this is same as foreach, OP want solution not in linear time over number of lines and number of character in each line. Summary i think this is slower than foreach, linq is slow because it is not way to fast working solutions, only for fast write slow working.

Comment: @Svisstack: I already said that it's the same as `foreach`. I think it's pretty obvious that if you want a solution that searches every line *then you'll need to search every line*. You may think that LINQ is slower than `foreach`, but I'd be very surprised if you could find a meaningful difference between this particular query and its `foreach` equivalent in most real-world situations.

Answer (score 4):

```
var newList = (from line in responseLines
              where line.StartsWith("abc") || line.Contains("xyz")
              select line).ToList();
```

Comment: This iterating over each character in each line.

Comment: @Svisstack: we heard you; you don't need to downvote each answer and repeat yourself. Besides, you're wrong in your downvoting: the answers correctly solve the question, so no downvoting is indicated as per the FAQs.

Comment: The question did specifically ask whether there is a "better/faster" way. If you take that to mean "better and faster" (as opposed to "better or faster"), then none of these answers actually answer the question.

Comment: It seems like this Svisstack guy is downrating each response without providing a good alternative. So dear Svisstack, since you're downrating everything, explain your enlightened way to do this without using iteration. Oh, yes, I almost forgot. You can't. Because what is asked simply CANNOT BE DONE without iteration.

Comment: @Svisstack: instead of downvoting each answer provide a better one yourself!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
List<string> responseLines = new List<string>();
List<string> myLines = responseLines.Where(line => line.StartsWith("abc", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || line.Contains("xyz")).ToList();
```

The `StartsWith` and `Contains` shortcut - the `Contains` will only evaluate if the `StartsWith` is not satisfied. This still iterates the whole list, but of course there is no way to avoid that if you want to check the whole list, but it saves you from <strike>doing</strike> typing a `foreach`.

Comment: This iterating over each character in each line.

Comment: @Svisstack - it is hard to avoid that when doing a Contains, the best thing you can do is avoid the Contains if it is not necessary on that line due to another condition being met first. At least we are letting any smarts built into LINQ do the character iteration. I don't see you proposing a solution that avoids this?

Answer (score 3):

Use LINQ:

```
List<string> list = responseLines.Where(x => x.StartsWith("abc") || x.Contains("xyz")).ToList();
```

Comment: This iterating over each character in each line.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you need all the text for some reason, it would be quicker to inspect each line at the time when you were generating the `List` and discard the ones that don't match without ever adding them.

This depends on how the `List` is loaded as well - that code is not shown.  This would be effective if you were reading from a text file since then you could just use your LINQ query to operate directly on the input data using [File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) as the source instead of the final `List<string>`.

```
    var query = File.ReadLines("input.txt").
        Where(s => s.StartsWith("abc") || s.Contains("xyz"))
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

LINQ works well as far as offering you improved syntax for this sort of thing (See LukeH's answer for a good example), but it isn't any faster than iterating over it by hand.

If you need to do this operation often, you might want to come up with some kind of indexed data structure that watches for all "abc" or "xyz" strings as they come into the list, and can thereby use a faster algorithm for serving them up when asked, rather than iterating through the whole list.

If you don't have to do it often, it's probably a "premature optimization."

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, there is no possible algorithm that can guarantee you will never have to iterate through every item in the list.  However, it is possible to improve the *average* number of items you need to iterate through - sorting the list before you begin your search.  By doing so, the only times you would have to iterate through the entire list would be when it is filled with only "abc" and "xyz."

Assuming that it's not practical for you to have a pre-sorted list by the time you need to search through it, then the only way to improve the speed of your search would be to use a different data structure than a list - for example, a [binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree).